# XML XPath search with Python lxml fails to filter on text() output

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, elementtree

Probably missing something obvious - when I filter for general "a" nodes, I get to see their text - including the target link I want - just fine:

```
ipdb> print [x.text for x in root.xpath(u".//a")]
[u'\u0391\u03c0\u03bf\u03c3\u03cd\u03bd\u03b4\u03b5\u03c3\u03b7', None, ... ]
```

But when I filter for the specific text contained in the first 'a' element returned above, I get nothing:

```
ipdb> print [x.text for x in root.xpath(
    u".//a[text()=" + 
    u'\u0391\u03c0\u03bf\u03c3\u03cd\u03bd\u03b4\u03b5\u03c3\u03b7' + 
    u']'  )]
[]
ipdb>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There are two languages here: Python and XPath. Each of them has quoted strings.

When interpreting the Python syntax the content of the string passed to `.xpath()` (your XPath expression) is something like this: `.//a[text()=Some text]`. However literal strings of texts need to be quoted in XPath: `.//a[text()="Some text"]`. You then need to encode that in a Python string. Here you have a few alternatives:

```
.xpath('.//a[text()="Some text"]')
.xpath(".//a[text()=\"Some text\"]")
.xpath(""".//a[text()="Some text"]""")
```

Comment: Looks like SO’s syntax highlighting doesn’t like Python’s triple quotes…